# JQUERY function with background not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I found on this site an answer to my other question, which was, how do I make it so that when I mouse over one item, I change another CSS element, specifically, the background? I found the answer, which was this code. (I changed the variables)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".about").hover(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("border", "5px blue solid");
    });
    $(".about").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("border", "none");
    });
});
```

I then changed it to the following, so that it would change the background image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resume").hover(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(css/style/images/ace.png)";
    });
    $(".resume").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(css/style/images/apple.png)";
    });
});
```

Just to put some worries you may have to rest, I didn't forget my script tags, or to import Jquery from Microsoft. The first border example works now, but the background one won't.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="photoBackground" class="backgroundImage">

<div id="menuWrap">
 <ul id="menu">
  <li id="resume" class="resume"><a href="http://www.vhawley.com/resume">Resume</a></li>
   <li id="about" class="about"><a href="http://www.vhawley.com/about">About</a></li>
    <li id="gallery" class="gallery"><a href="http://www.vhawley.com/gallery">Gallery</li>
     <li id="contact" class="contact"><a href="http://www.vhawley.com/contact">Contact</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It would probably help if you included your HTML as well. Even better - replicate the issue here: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ok hold on one second, and I'll have the HTML code on here.

Comment: is `$(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(css/style/images/ace.png)";` writen as `$(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(css/style/images/ace.png)");` in youre code? (notice the tailing Parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your first example you're only setting the border property and in the second example you're only setting the background property.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu > li").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url('/css/style/images/ace.png')";
    });
    $("#menu > li").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url('/css/style/images/apple.png')";
    });
});
```

Comment: No, I don't want both, I am just having trouble getting the background to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
$(".resume").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url('/css/style/images/ace.png')";
});
$(".resume").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url('/css/style/images/apple.png')";
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it.

Comment: @Hunter you should try adding blue , red instead of the url's just to see if that works... b.c there could be an issue with the path

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `backgroundImage` from `background` as just background (short-hand property) doesn't work if you just place the url of image only, you should at least use `url('') no-repeat;` someting. For only one value you should use `backgroundImage` instead.

---

So, this must work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resume").hover(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("backgroundImage", "url(css/style/images/ace.png)";
    });
    $(".resume").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("backgroundImage", "url(css/style/images/apple.png)";
    });
});
```

---

But better use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resume").hover(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("backgroundImage", "url(css/style/images/ace.png)";
    },function(){
        $(".backgroundImage").css("backgroundImage", "url(css/style/images/apple.png)";
    });
});
```

It contains the mouseenter(first-function) and mouseleave (second-function).

---

Also try giving `overflow: hidden;` to `.backgroundImage` div which might solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

check out similar example from w3school [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
        },function(){
        $("p").css("background-color","pink");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `background-image` instead of `background`. Try

```
$('.backgroundImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

or,

```
$('.backgroundImage').css('background-image', 'url(path/to/your/image)');
```